# multiple checkbox with label and the same id

Tags: php

goody day. I have a problem here. I have used a custom label for my checkbox and i have set the checkbox to hidden where in only the label can be seen in a checkbox image.My problem now is that I have looped this checkbox.

```
<?php
    for($r=0;$r<5;r++;){
        print "<label for='cb'>"
        . "</label><input type='checkbox' name='name[]' id='cb' />";
    }
?>
```

that is just an example. What happens is when i click the label it wount work it always checks the first checkbox. how could i fix this. sorry for the english. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: use class, not id. Id is for 1 element.

Comment: i have tried it still not working.maybe it's because of my css. here is the code  `.table td input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
 content: "\2713";
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #666;
 text-align: center;
    line-height: 10px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

id always should be a unique value. so use this

```
for($r=0;$r<5;$r++){
     print "<label for='cb-$r'>"
    . "</label><input type='checkbox' name='name[]' id='cb-$r' />";
}
```

Comment: Error syntax in your for.